# Python modeling for ILP Minimum Dominating Set (MDS)

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, python

I'm writing a code for solving the **MDS** problem, the problem is:
\begin{align}\min&\quad\sum_{v\in V}y_v\\\text{s.t.}&\quad y_v+\sum_{(u,v)\in E}y_u\ge1\quad\forall v\in V\\&\quad y_v\in\{0,1\}\quad\forall v\in V.\end{align}

I have used **Pulp** and **nx.network** in python to model the problem as following:

- The problem `prob = pulp.LpProblem("MinimumDominatingSet", pulp.LpMinimize)`
- Variables `y = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("y", g.nodes(), cat=pulp.LpBinary)`
- The objective `for (v,u) in g.edges(): prob += pulp.lpSum(y)`
- Constraint `for (v,u) in g.edges():   prob += y.get(v) + sum(y.get(u) for (v,u) in g.edges) >= 1`

I have tried to test the output with a simple star figure. Unfortunately, the output is not correct.
I'm suspecting there may be an issue with modeling the constraint.

Could anyone guide me through this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your objective should be `prob+= pulp.lpSum(y)`, and the constraints should be :

```
for v in g.nodes():
       prob += y[v] + pulp.lpSum([y[u] for u in g.neighbors(v)]) >= 1
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help. thank you so much. I didn't know that nx.network class has the neighbors' attribute.

Comment: nx has simplified my life so many times ! pulp too in fact ! great tools