# Summation of all links that contains nieghbors to certain node in Graph

Tags: optimization, python

I'm trying to model a constraint in Python using Pulp and networkX that is getting the sum of the edges that contain this node over all the nodes. The constraint can be like that:
$$\sum_{m\in\cal N}z_{(m,n)}\succeq k(1-y_m),\quad\forall m\in\cal N.$$

I have used this code to model the constraint:

`for m in g.nodes(): prob +=  pulp.lpSum(z[(m,n)] for m in g.nodes()) >= k*(1-y[m])`

This piece of code rises an error about the key of the dictionary since the variable dictionary $z$ doesn't contains all the neighbors values. If I used this instead

`for m in g.nodes(): prob +=  pulp.lpSum(z[(m,n)] for (u,v) in g.edges()) >= k*(1-y[m])`

It sums all the links, not the ones associated with link $m$.

I would like your help with this!.

Please be noted that $z_{(m,n)}$ is a dict of the graph edges

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternatively, just like in your [previous question](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/5196/python-modeling-for-ilp-minimum-dominating-set-mds) :

```
for m in g.nodes():
    prob += pulp.lpSum(z[(m,n)] for n in g.neighbors(m)) >= k*(1-y[m])
```

Comment: Thank you @Kuifje. I have tried this actually before asking but it throws an error about the key of the dict. For example, If I have this small set of edges 
[ [(1,2),(1,4),(1,5),(2,5),(2,3),(3,5),(3,4),(4,5)] ]
The optimizer throws an error as  KeyError: (2, 1). I think this is because the dict of Z which is the dict of edges doesn't contain the value of z_(2,1)

Comment: First, I think there is an extra set of brackets in your set of edges. This may be what triggrs the KeyError. Second, I suggest you post your full code in another question, so that we can see everything and help you with that.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  The extra brackets are not in the code, they are here by mistake. However, I will post another question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
all_neighbors(graph, node): Returns all of the neighbors of a node in the graph.
```

function in networkX to find all the nodes which are connected to node m and then use the first constraint that you mentioned. I think there is a typo in the constraint as well instead of $m$ you should have $n$ (it's confusing). The output of that function is `iterator` you need to save it as a list (I am not sure about the format that PuLP accept).

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Ogzu.

Comment: @OguzToragay's comment is relevant : because of the typo, you got your $u$ and $v$ mixed up in the last constraint.